# How to set a start value for a primefaces extension timer

Tags: primefaces, timer, startup, primefaces-extensions

I use a primefaces extension timer with the following code :

```
<pe:timer 
    style="color:darkgrey;"
    timeout="1000"
    forward="false" 
    format="HH:mm:ss"/>
```

But I have a start value. The previous code start from the value 00:00:00, but I have a start time from a Java bean. I have a Date object, or date as long type (from 1970) which is the value from I want to start.

For example I got 1548434800083 or 17:47 25/01/2019 and I want to display the time between this date and now. So how I can set my start value with this date ? I got milliseconds but I can get seconds instead of.

Comment: Why not use the "formatFunction" attribute from the showcase: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/timer/format.jsf . It will let you take the current value and manipulate and display it any way you want. So you could do your own math from your "start" date to show whatever you wanted.

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean, thank you for the sample link. I have a value from a Java bean like "#{synopticWipIdBean.referenceTime}"; I give it to the function like that : formatFunction="return formatMe('#{synopticBean.longEnteredTime}');" but my counter doesn't count. What is my mistake ?

Comment: I think you get passed the curent value of the timer in that javascript function.  You will have to do Math and subtract that value from your date value to do a countdown.  If you just do what you did above its just displaying your same date over and over and over.

Comment: Remarkable btw, I'm 100% I also discussed the formatFunction solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is the following, I have a Java bean, that contain a date in millisecond. I get it with the function getTime() from the Java class Date.

I display my counter, chronometer with the primefaces code :

```
<pe:timer 
   style="color:grey;"
   forward="true" 
   formatFunction="return displayElapsedTime('#{synopticBean.longEnteredTime}');"/>
```

That code call a javascript function, that return a format counter/chronometer :

```
function displayElapsedTime(longEnteredTime){
        var now = new Date();
        var elapsedTime = now.getTime() - longEnteredTime;
        var numHours = Math.floor(elapsedTime / 3600000);

        var minutesAndSecondMS = elapsedTime - numHours;
        var minutes = Math.floor((minutesAndSecondMS % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((minutesAndSecondMS % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        var innerHtmlText = (('0' + (numHours)).slice(-2) + ":" +('0' + (minutes)).slice(-2) + ":" + ('0' + (seconds)).slice(-2));

        return innerHtmlText;
    }
```

It display a duration, the number of hours. I only count with hours, no day.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution for your case is formatting. But sometime we need to set start value of primefaces timer:

Run javascript:

```
PF('timer').currentTimeout = 100;
```